# How to set up wake word for Google Assistant SDK on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

Documentation of the [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/getting-started-pi-python/run-sample) says that you need to hit enter to talk to the assistant. Is there a native way to set up a wake word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not yet. Remember this is just the first Alpha release. As noted in the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/release-notes), "Library with hotwording capabilities" is "Coming Soon".

However... this does mean that you have the flexibility to wake up the assistant based on whatever you want. The sample makes you hit enter, but you can set it up to trigger based on other things. Consider, for example, turning on the microphone when someone opens the door and after a welcome greeting is played.

Answer (score 6):

Also consider using Snowboy - https://snowboy.kitt.ai/ - it supports Python and a variety of other languages, runs on Mac/Linux (including Pi) and supports multiple hotword detection. And its free for non-commercial use.

Answer (score 4):

It as been implemented in a recent update, follow the instructions on this page.

https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/tree/master/google-assistant-sdk

If you have already installed it on Raspberry Pi 3, you can just update the library and it will work.

EDIT:

**Installation steps and sample code, in case the link becomes inactivated**

I am assuming you already have a virtual environment, as part of the previous installation. So, you can skip this step, else follow it.

Setup of virtual environment:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-venv
$ python3 -m venv env
$ env/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

Activate virtual environment:

```
$ source env/bin/activate
```

Download the latest linux_arm7l wheel for the google_assistant_library from the [GitHub releases page](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/releases).

Install the google_assistant_library wheel and the samples dependencies using pip:

```
pip install --upgrade google_assistant_library-0.0.2-py2.py3-none-linux_armv7l.whl
pip install --upgrade google-assistant-sdk[samples]
```

Try the hotword sample:

```
googlesamples-assistant-hotword
```

In case you get urllib3 version error after running the last command, upgrade urllib3. (I faced this issue while I was installing it):

```
pip install --upgrade urllib3
```

**NOTE:** It works only with Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and Python 3.x as of 5/31/17, the installation steps may vary with a new release.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the relevant code/info from your link, in case it ever becomes dead.

Answer (score 0):

I found in my setup the following needed to be added otherwise got alsorts of errors

```
sudo apt-get install **python-dev** python3-dev python3-venv
pip install cryptography
pip install --upgrade **\path\to\file\**google_assistant_library-0.0.2-py2.py3-none-linux_armv7l.whl
```